# Why is the walk cycle not working?

Tags: animation

I have a 32-frame walk animation and have converted it to action. With the first and 250 last frames I set the keyframe as a walk cycle. When I hit play it just walks 32 frames and then slides the rest of the frames.

[image]

[image]

I have set the repeat option (8 repeat). It walks, but not as a normal continuous walk cycle. Where am I going wrong or what else do I have to do to make it a complete walk?

[image]

**Pose Mode**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your character is moving forwards both in *Pose* mode and in *Object* mode. I guess it's your problem.

Most of the time, when you create a repetitive walk cycle in *Pose* mode, you'll make your character (i.e. his root bone) stand "still" on the X and Y axis, like if he was walking on a treadmill. It's only once in *Object* mode that you'll make the whole armature move forwards, either with a *Follow Path* constraint or just making him move from point A to point B with keyframes.

It's the combination of treadmill animation and movement in the scene that will recreate the illusion of walk.

Making an armature move forwards in *Pose* mode (i.e. moving its root bone or moving the other bones away from the root bone) is only useful for small moves through the scene, or for some complex and non-repetitive movements, and in that case you generally won't make him move in *Object* mode.

Comment: Did not work in pose mode also plz check the question above update

Comment: is your walk cycle stationary in Pose mode (i.e. like on a treadmill). If it is not, do it this way, and then, in Object mode, move your object forward.

Comment: i have got that walk animation from mixamo website. Is there any issue regarding it.

Comment: perhaps the one I'm explaining   ;)  perhaps share your file (at least the armature)

Comment: plz check the file in question

Comment: the problem is exactly the one I try to explain: if, in Pose mode, you check the armature animation called "Armature|mixamo.com|Layer0", you'll see that the armature will move forward when it should stay still like walking on a treadmill. So what happens on your scene? It repeats the same animation consisting on going forward then back to its start point and again forward and back, etc... you've given an animation to the whole armature but it just makes this back and forth animation going forward... What do you need to do? Create a treadmill walk animation !

Comment: im just beginner to learn the walk cycle. Seen video to make walk cycle with the mixamo website. So can u plz explain in the answer with my file how it will work. Little in detail. Thanks

Comment: wow it's a little bit hard on a forum, please search tutorials on youtube, you'll find a lot   ;)

Comment: That what i want to learn. If u make little steps or give reference video maybe it will be clear.

Comment: for example this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DuUWxUitJos&

Answer (score 0):

I would also in the first instance use repeat, but increase it by a few increments

[image]